# Invalidate/Clear all JWT tokens for a Laravel App

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I am deploying a Laravel backend app that is being used as an API service for a frontend app, and a lot of breaking changes were made to the laest version of the app, is it possible to invalidate all the jwt tokens used for athentication so all users making requests from the APIs will have to re-authenticate.

NOTE: The tokens are not stored on the database

I have tried

`php artisan jwt:generate`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`
but still the jwt tokens are still valid.

Comment: Remove the existing keys for signing/validation and create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

JWT tokens are signed using a secret key. By changing the secret key, all previously issued JWT tokens will become invalid. Run the following command:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

This worked for me, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do to invalidate all the JWT tokens coming to the backend since all the tokens are encoded and decoded based on the JWT secret changing this token will require re-authentication of the user. Hope this resolves your issue.

If you are using **jwt-auth** php package then here is a command that might be helpful.

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

[jwt-auth documentation for generating new JWT secret key.](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/#generate-secret-key)

Comment: You more or less just repeated the existing answer that was posted more than 30 minutes earlier.

Comment: Ya my bad, I typed the answer and had to wait for whole 30 minutes to post it, because of lack of reputation stackoverflow did not allow me to post the answer. And later when I posted it you commented it being as a duplicate, its fine unless it resolves the main thread issue.